# On hover change image button inside picture

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images one inactive another active I need when someone hover on inactive part of picture to change that part to active, here are pictures:

[image]

[image]

I done it with mapster but not reposnsive any other way to do that?

Comment: There's hundreds of similar answers already here on SO. Use Goog, use the SO search. I'm sure that while you were writing your title the site returned you with already posted similar questions. Show some code. Show what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this, might give you some idea

HTML

```
<div class="layer">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hrG46JH.png" alt="tablet" width="380" height="563" border="0" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="34,87,182,199" href="#" id="idOne">
        <area shape="rect" coords="200,83,352,207" href="#" id="idtwo">
        <area shape="rect" coords="33,228,182,348" href="#" id="idthree">
        <area shape="rect" coords="33,381,183,497" href="#" id="idfive">
        <area shape="rect" coords="201,380,352,498" href="#" id="idsix">
        <area shape="rect" coords="202,233,350,345" href="#" id="idfour">
    </map>
    <div class="id-1"></div>
    <div class="id-2"></div>
    <div class="id-3"></div>
    <div class="id-4"></div>
    <div class="id-5"></div>
    <div class="id-6"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.layer {
    position:relative;
    width:380px;
    height:563px;
}
.id-1, .id-2, .id-3, .id-4, .id-5, .id-6 {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/nboEjPb.png);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
}
.id-1 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 205px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-position: 0px 564px;
}
.id-2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 205px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-position: -200px 564px;
}
.id-3 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 129px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 224px;
    background-position:0px 340px;
}
.id-4 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 129px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 224px;
    background-position:-200px 340px;
}
.id-5 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 129px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 377px;
    background-position:0px 187px;
}
.id-6 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 129px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 377px;
    background-position:-200px 187px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idOne, .id-1").mouseover(function() {
        $('.id-1').show();
    });
    $("#idOne, .id-1").mouseout(function() {
        $('.id-1').hide()
    });

    $("#idtwo, .id-2").mouseover(function() {
        $('.id-2').show();
    });
    $("#idtwo, .id-2").mouseout(function() {
        $('.id-2').hide()
    });

    $("#idthree, .id-3").mouseover(function() {
        $('.id-3').show();
    });
    $("#idthree, .id-3").mouseout(function() {
        $('.id-3').hide()
    });

    $("#idfour, .id-4").mouseover(function() {
        $('.id-4').show();
    });
    $("#idfour, .id-4").mouseout(function() {
        $('.id-4').hide()
    });

    $("#idfive, .id-5").mouseover(function() {
        $('.id-5').show();
    });
    $("#idfour, .id-5").mouseout(function() {
        $('.id-5').hide()
    });

    $("#idsix, .id-6").mouseover(function() {
        $('.id-6').show();
    });
    $("#idfour, .id-6").mouseout(function() {
        $('.id-6').hide()
    });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/snavaneeth78/t7cud3bw/3/